# Error when archiving iOS App - "generic specialization <Swift.String> of Swift.String.init"

Tags: ios, swift, archive

My iOS app builds and runs just fine, but I'm getting this error when trying to archive:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
>
> generic specialization  of Swift.String.init(stringInterpolationSegment: A) -> Swift.String", referenced from: ...

Answer (score 0):

Try extending `CustomStringConvertible` for the object you were trying to print or access its correspond string value

[Apple's Swift Documentation: CustomStringConverible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)